# Connecting SAS drives to Server which supports only SATA

Tags: windows-server-2008, connection, sas, sata, adapter

Is there any adapter or connector available to connect a SAS drive to a Server having motherboard which supports only SATA drives. It is ok if can connect it for temporary. I need to transfer some data from SAS driver to a server which supports only SATA. So please help if any connectors available?

Edit:

I have a server which has SAS drives and have RAID 0 or 1. In case the server fails due to motherboard problem or any other failure then i may need to transfer the data from that SAS drive to another PC which supports only SATA, no SAS. So it is just to transfer the data once,not to connect the SAS drive permanently to it.

Comment: are both servers online?  using something like DFS-R might be a much easier way than dealing with moving the drives back and forth.  There is a SAS to SATA adapter, but I doubt you will be able to read the drive without the original controller and backplane.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called a SAS-based disk controller :)

There's nothing else to be done I'm afraid, SAS disks are *generally* SATA-capable but not the other way around sorry.

Comment: So no solution for my requiremnt?

Comment: Yes and no, you need a controller that 'speaks' SAS, there's no 'adapter' as such, but you could just buy a super-cheapo SAS controller for the job, they're not too expensive.

Comment: [Oh my...](http://serverfault.com/questions/565018/connecting-sata-3-to-sas-port-performance-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

A few questions first...

- Where did the SAS drive come from?
- Was it part of a server? A workstation?
- Did the SAS drive come from a system that contained a RAID controller?
- How was the SAS drive connected to the origin system?

Based on the answers to the above, you should be able to figure out how to use the drive on your target system.

Ideally, you would use the same type of controller or adapter that was used on the source system.

Comment: Please see my updated question